# Created column isn't calculating as expected

Tags: powerbi

I have two calculated columns from my dataset. I am trying to get a % figure based on these columns. As you can see from the picture below the columns calculate correctly and have been sorted by operatorname as I would hope but the % calculation hasn't worked. I would expect the abort % column to be 15/66 = 0.227 and so on but that's not what I'm seeing. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment asking for raw data. I'm using direct query but here is a sample

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+------------+
|                                              rhOutcome                                               |     rhStartTime     | rhAccountNo |           rhOperatorName            | rhCallRef  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+------------+
| PROCESS_COMPLETE                                                                                     | 19/09/2018 00:02:06 |      106874 | Kevin Jones                         | 8GVHTXUK   |
| START_END_CALLOUT_IWORK                                                                              | 19/09/2018 00:21:44 |      225080 | Claire Miley                        | SKALW2VR   |
| CREATE_JOB_SADC                                                                                      | 19/09/2018 01:07:54 |      141116 | Claire Miley                        | DK9JSTK8   |
| QUERY_RESOLVED                                                                                       | 19/09/2018 01:16:40 |      106836 | Kevin Jones                         | J2RFLY8C   |
| PROCESS_COMPLETE                                                                                     | 19/09/2018 01:14:01 |      106874 | Kevin Jones                         | F7K33MPM   |
| ADDITIONAL_REF_DATA_CAPTURE_END_SAC                                                                  | 19/09/2018 01:11:12 |      141590 | Claire Miley                        | CKLYJPDA   |
| ABORT                                                                                                | 19/09/2018 01:28:37 |      225080 | Claire Miley                        | UY38NRNL   |
| PROCESS_COMPLETE                                                                                     | 19/09/2018 01:09:42 |      106874 | Kevin Jones                         | NQFWC76W   |
| CALL_PASSED                                                                                          | 19/09/2018 01:05:50 |       70018 | Kevin Jones                         | TD7DMDN9   |
| END_CALL                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 01:29:52 |      310523 | Martyn Jones                        | W76MWX22   |
| CHECK_IN_REMINDER_SAC                                                                                | 19/09/2018 01:01:01 |      141475 | Claire Miley                        | GW8YKMGW   |
| JOB_NOT_COMPLETE                                                                                     | 19/09/2018 01:00:21 |      141116 | Claire Miley                        | 5JZA6977   |
| TIMER_SET_SAC                                                                                        | 19/09/2018 00:57:01 |      310739 | Kevin Jones                         | D5Z69P4T   |
| SPAM_EMAIL                                                                                           | 19/09/2018 01:39:52 |      911804 | Margaret Weir                       | Q6RH25RJ   |
| GEN_ENQUIRY_CLOSE_SAC                                                                                | 19/09/2018 00:54:06 |      833694 | Margaret Weir                       | 8Z88KU94   |
| ALARM_ACTIAVTION_CLOSE_SAC                                                                           | 19/09/2018 00:53:16 |      833694 | Martyn Jones                        | Q2RTWHFT   |
| ALARM_ACTIAVTION_CLOSE_SAC                                                                           | 19/09/2018 00:50:47 |      833694 | Kevin Jones                         | BXC5UJ6Q   |
| ABORT                                                                                                | 19/09/2018 00:48:40 |      316084 | Martyn Jones                        | AUH3Z5H9   |
| SEND_DETAILS_BY_SMS                                                                                  | 19/09/2018 00:30:14 |      225110 | Claire Miley                        | T4TS42X3   |
| ABORTED_CALL                                                                                         | 19/09/2018 00:25:09 |      155357 | Kevin Jones                         | 5G2HZQCA   |
| JOB_PASSED                                                                                           | 19/09/2018 02:07:20 |      911983 | Margaret Weir                       | 2648PN38   |
| PROCESS_COMPLETE                                                                                     | 19/09/2018 02:07:30 |      106874 | Martyn Jones                        | H7ND6DWQ   |
| NO_MESSAGE_DATA                                                                                      | 19/09/2018 02:09:03 |      310169 | Kevin Jones                         | Z694XH4V   |
| JOB_NOT_COMPLETE                                                                                     | 19/09/2018 00:24:11 |      141116 | Claire Miley                        | TJBWRBQY   |
| END_CALL                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 00:17:42 |      310523 | Kevin Jones                         | T8WPXCU6   |
| CODE_NOT_WORKING_BLUE_RESOLVED                                                                       | 19/09/2018 02:15:21 |      106836 | Kevin Jones                         | 63NHPC7N   |
| OOH_NO_MESSAGE_DATA                                                                                  | 19/09/2018 02:19:10 |      310169 | Martyn Jones                        | 62RX9BP3   |
| ABORTED_CALL                                                                                         | 19/09/2018 00:15:49 |      155357 | Martyn Jones                        | VSAMDWDG   |
| END_CALL                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 00:14:25 |      310523 | Kevin Jones                         | YCAWLGBE   |
| END_CALL                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 00:11:03 |      310523 | Kevin Jones                         | GXRCMQHU   |
| ABORT                                                                                                | 19/09/2018 00:10:10 |      140014 | Claire Miley                        | BQ72RRNR   |
| CALL_ANSWERED_PASSED_SAC                                                                             | 19/09/2018 00:09:56 |       31206 | Martyn Jones                        | LDTMFJSS   |
| END_CALL                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 00:05:24 |      310523 | Martyn Jones                        | VJLFGBL6   |
| JOB_UPDATE_DATA                                                                                      | 19/09/2018 00:03:01 |      911804 | Margaret Weir                       | 2L4WHNQB   |
| TIMER_SET_SAC                                                                                        | 19/09/2018 00:01:17 |      310739 | Martyn Jones                        | XY84B498   |
| PROCESS_COMPLETE                                                                                     | 19/09/2018 01:18:46 |      106874 | Kevin Jones                         | ZYGREQ7D   |
| SPAM_EMAIL                                                                                           | 19/09/2018 01:23:21 |      911804 | Margaret Weir                       | Z9DZNN2V   |
| END_CALL                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 01:28:51 |      310523 | Kevin Jones                         | 3YY8YPDB   |
| END_CALL                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 01:29:34 |      310523 | Kevin Jones                         | AGJP82H8   |
| NO_CALLOUT_REQUIRED                                                                                  | 19/09/2018 01:07:54 |      141116 | Claire Miley                        | DK9JSTK8   |
| ETA_ADVICE_GIVEN_SAC                                                                                 | 19/09/2018 01:30:14 |      911968 | Margaret Weir                       | PKTXU2JX   |
| END_CALL                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 01:37:49 |      310523 | Martyn Jones                        | AP7CUYA4   |
| ABORTED_CALL                                                                                         | 19/09/2018 01:55:06 |      155357 | Martyn Jones                        | MZHEW6SU   |
| JOB_NOT_COMPLETE                                                                                     | 19/09/2018 02:13:31 |      141116 | Claire Miley                        | BAYYPWJZ   |
| MESSAGE                                                                                              | 19/09/2018 02:56:18 |      106871 | Martyn Jones                        | YV3AXSWP   |
| ABORT                                                                                                | 19/09/2018 02:19:16 |      140014 | Claire Miley                        | 9C82J6M5   |
| NO_MESSAGE_SAC                                                                                       | 19/09/2018 02:23:19 |      106871 | Kevin Jones                         | AVTASU7U   |
| NO_MESSAGE_SAC                                                                                       | 19/09/2018 02:24:03 |      106871 | Kevin Jones                         | JNE3J723   |
| MESSAGE                                                                                              | 19/09/2018 02:24:46 |      106871 | Kevin Jones                         | F8MVAHSP   |
| DECLINE_TO_LEAVE_DETAILS_SAC                                                                         | 19/09/2018 02:27:09 |      141590 | Claire Miley                        | AKYGGB6M   |
| MESSAGE                                                                                              | 19/09/2018 02:29:11 |      106866 | Martyn Jones                        | 7VEC5EY3   |
| TECH_SUPPORT_NEW_PATCH_FAILED                                                                        | 19/09/2018 02:29:11 |      911248 | Margaret Weir                       | ZCXZD8WG   |
| END_CALL                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 02:42:46 |      310523 | Kevin Jones                         | G2RRM5BT   |
| MESSAGE                                                                                              | 19/09/2018 03:18:47 |      106871 | Kevin Jones                         | QEG7CUWC   |
| OOH_FAULT_CLS                                                                                        | 19/09/2018 02:46:46 |      911667 | Margaret Weir                       | 8UW2M9LH   |
| NO_MESSAGE_SAC                                                                                       | 19/09/2018 02:48:24 |      106871 | Martyn Jones                        | CZWBPZ9U   |
| NO_MESSAGE_SAC                                                                                       | 19/09/2018 02:49:05 |      106871 | Kevin Jones                         | QLHT6UBT   |
| MESSAGE                                                                                              | 19/09/2018 02:49:41 |      106871 | Martyn Jones                        | N4WVGDVM   |
| ABORT                                                                                                | 19/09/2018 02:52:53 |      190001 | Kevin Jones                         | 6GLUHVSG   |
| END_CALL                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 01:32:35 |      310523 | Martyn Jones                        | KZ759EYC   |
| ABORTED_CALL                                                                                         | 19/09/2018 01:55:00 |      155357 | Martyn Jones                        | CBT8HUFL   |
| END_CALL                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 02:55:05 |      310523 | Kevin Jones                         | D3XMG9W6   |
| ABORT                                                                                                | 19/09/2018 01:56:41 |      310470 | Martyn Jones                        | C3BRA65U   |
| TIMER_SET_SAC                                                                                        | 19/09/2018 01:59:10 |      310739 | Martyn Jones                        | 54Q67QUK   |
| JOB_UPDATED                                                                                          | 19/09/2018 04:48:12 |      141116 | Claire Miley                        | Y8T6SZ4U   |
| ABORT                                                                                                | 19/09/2018 02:00:05 |      911626 | Margaret Weir                       | V2Y5M3LS   |
| DETAILS_PASSED_DATA                                                                                  | 19/09/2018 02:02:58 |      141371 | Claire Miley                        | J6HRFM8F   |
| SAVE_AND_CLOSE                                                                                       | 19/09/2018 03:01:13 |      310827 | Kevin Jones                         | 6A6Q9KYU   |
| TIMER_SET_SAC                                                                                        | 19/09/2018 03:01:50 |      310739 | Martyn Jones                        | 9CV8DWXN   |
| MESSAGE                                                                                              | 19/09/2018 03:07:20 |      106871 | Martyn Jones                        | U9BC3GNC   |
| JOB_PASSED                                                                                           | 19/09/2018 03:09:08 |      911982 | Margaret Weir                       | GHUQWW3T   |
| CREATE_JOB_SADC                                                                                      | 19/09/2018 03:16:13 |      141116 | Claire Miley                        | 8YT5XA5U   |
| JOB_NOT_COMPLETE                                                                                     | 19/09/2018 02:37:41 |      141116 | Claire Miley                        | 2FEBSCJJ   |
| ABORT                                                                                                | 19/09/2018 03:24:30 |      140014 | Claire Miley                        | GZ2CYXJH   |
| QUERY_RESOLVED                                                                                       | 19/09/2018 04:23:11 |      106836 | Martyn Jones                        | GSA6QACH   |
| ABORT                                                                                                | 19/09/2018 02:53:09 |      190001 | Martyn Jones                        | 2FLFK95G   |
| NEW_ORDER                                                                                            | 19/09/2018 04:48:47 |      310722 | Martyn Jones                        | BMW4G3WA   |
| OOH_NO_MESSAGE_DATA                                                                                  | 19/09/2018 02:14:42 |      310169 | Martyn Jones                        | RZB86GEC   |
| CREATE_JOB_SADC                                                                                      | 19/09/2018 04:54:19 |      141116 | Claire Miley                        | Q2YWAJP7   |
| NEXT_PRODUCT                                                                                         | 19/09/2018 05:09:32 |      310169 | Martyn Jones                        | RMD3KLZT   |
| END_CALL                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 03:08:42 |      310523 | Kevin Jones                         | YRY52DEU   |
| NO_CALLOUT_REQUIRED                                                                                  | 19/09/2018 03:16:13 |      141116 | Claire Miley                        | 8YT5XA5U   |
| CLOSE_APPLICATION                                                                                    | 19/09/2018 05:00:25 |      911626 | Margaret Weir                       | 8J6T9BFK   |
| NFU_ALREADY_ACCEPTED_SAC                                                                             | 19/09/2018 03:23:22 |      911982 | Margaret Weir                       | V4G3BD2X   |
| SEND_SMS                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 05:00:25 |      911626 | Margaret Weir                       | 8J6T9BFK   |
| ALL_JOBS_UPDATED                                                                                     | 19/09/2018 04:48:12 |      141116 | Claire Miley                        | Y8T6SZ4U   |
| ABORT                                                                                                | 19/09/2018 05:28:35 |      225080 | Claire Miley                        | D9TUGKZH   |
| JOB_UPDATED                                                                                          | 19/09/2018 04:54:18 |      141116 | Claire Miley                        | Q2YWAJP7   |
| END_CALL                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 03:25:26 |      310523 | Martyn Jones                        | 2WNTZN73   |
| END_CALL                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 05:26:40 |      310523 | Martyn Jones                        | GB2MK7RW   |
| TIMER_SET_SAC                                                                                        | 19/09/2018 03:57:51 |      310739 | Kevin Jones                         | MTXW2RPJ   |
| JOB_NOT_COMPLETE                                                                                     | 19/09/2018 04:08:21 |      141116 | Claire Miley                        | KXCN3QSF   |
| ADDITIONAL_REF_DATA_CAPTURE_END_SAC                                                                  | 19/09/2018 04:12:04 |      141590 | Claire Miley                        | LNQVW7NJ   |
| SEND_EMAIL                                                                                           | 19/09/2018 05:00:25 |      911626 | Margaret Weir                       | 8J6T9BFK   |
| SEND_SMS                                                                                             | 19/09/2018 05:00:25 |      911626 | Margaret Weir                       | 8J6T9BFK   |
| NEW_ORDER                                                                                            | 19/09/2018 04:28:29 |      310722 | Martyn Jones                        | 6CFPCDD6   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: What does your data table look like?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I've added some sample data to my question

Comment: That helps. How are your `[Total Aborts]` and `[Total Outcomes]` measures defined? And are they actually measures or are they calculated columns?

Comment: @AlexisOlson yeah they are calculated.

Answer (score 0):

In your table, the values in the `Abort %` column are summing the `Abort %` row values for each row in your `ires` table. Each of your rows in `ires[Abort %]` is the `0.227` you are expecting, but it's getting summed up for each of the `66` rows: `(15/66) * 66 = 15.0`.

To fix this, switch `Abort %` from *Sum* to *Don't summarize*.

[image: Don't Summarize]

Comment: The don't summarize option left everything as 1. I tried the average option instead and that worked. Not sure if I should accept your answer or not can anyone weigh in?

Comment: Average should work fine. If Don't summarize isn't working, then your total columns weren't defined how I expected. What formulas did you use for those calculated columns?